# POST over SSL with OAuth-PHP

Tags: php, post, curl, https, oauth-php

I'm using the oauth-php library to do oauth calls to a remote server, but the remote server is not being passed the variables. It works fine when I connect to an http server, but not over https. I tested this with multiple servers and set up a proxy is to examine the calls.

Is there a reason that the POST variables are not being delivered via https? The variables are being put correctly into the curl calls, as tested with an http connection, but are not going out to the server I need it to.

Comment: https is http over ssl, there is no reason for post vars to appear in http request, but not appear in https request

Comment: I know there's no reason it should only be in http and not https, but I don't know why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem. If anyone else ever has it, cUrl blocks SSL by default and either needs to ignore certificates or define it. Full info can be found at http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/